# Force wrapping the long output lines that aren't so in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

Usually when the long lines are output in terminal/console/xterm, they will be wrapped automatically. However, there are cases that are not. `ps` is one of such cases -- it cuts the output right at the windows width.

```
 ps ax | grep [d]nsmasq
 4459 ?        S      0:03 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsm
```

For the `dnsmasq`, even I maximize my xterm, the output is still being cut.

I've tried,

```
 $ ps ax | fold | grep [d]nsmasq
 4459 ?        S      0:03 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsm

 $ ps ax | grep [d]nsmasq | fold
 4459 ?        S      0:03 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsm

 $ ps ax | grep [d]nsmasq | fold --spaces
 4459 ?        S      0:03 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsm
```

Such cutting make `ps` seems like not writing to standard output, but its responding to `grep` proves otherwise. But how come the `fold` not working then?

How to wrapping such long lines to show everything instead of cutting to the windows' width?

Answer (score 5):

The quick fix that I can remember is to do :
$ ps -ef | cat

This way ps sees the pipe as the environment to do the output on and will not truncate lines.

Answer (score 2):

Duh, found the answer soon after I asked it.

```
COLUMNS=500 ps ax | grep [d]nsmasq | fold
```

The same trick works for `dpkg` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check the man page. Compare these 3 outputs:

```
ps ax
ps axw
ps axww
```

Comment: w, -w    Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.

Answer (score 1):

`ps` checks whether its output goes to a terminal, and if so, queries the terminal's width. Then `ps` itself truncates each line according to that width. It's not the terminal chopping them, it doesn't even receive this data.